# Calculate capacitance i.a. via reactive power

Tags: power, capacitor, capacitance, reactive-power

The ampermeter of the following circuit shows **10A (AC)** and the voltmeter **220V (AC)**.

[image]

Furthermore its known that:

$$ cos\varphi=\frac{2}{3} \\ f=50Hz $$

I calculated the following:
$$
P=UIcos\varphi =1466.67W \\
Q=UIsin\varphi = UIsin(arccos(\frac{2}{3}))=1639.78var \\
R=\frac{P}{I^2}=14.67\Omega 
$$

Now I also want to know the capacitance C. I found the solution to be:
$$
C=\frac{I^2}{2\pi fQ}=\frac{I}{2\pi fUsin\varphi}=94,1\mu F
$$
But I do not really understand the formula. Can someone explain me how it is derived?

Comment: Which formula don't you understand and what is cos(squiggly thing) meant to represent?

Comment: Well, the last one, for the capacitance. The squiggly thing is a lowercase phi, the cos of that represents the power factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From impedance of capacitor $$Z_{c}=\frac{1}{j\omega C}$$, then the reactance is $$X{c}=\frac{1}{\omega C}$$ and reactive power is $$Q=I^2 X=\frac{U^2}{X}=\frac{I^2}{\omega C}$$ $$C=\frac{I^2}{\omega Q}$$